# AngularJS - forEach() with empty array from $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, foreach

I have an array that I get from a service but in the controller I get an empty value in the `forEach()` function. This is the [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/vwshgDYeCZHCwyFWtrYX?p=preview).

*Controller*

Here, both 'products' and 'copyProducts' are empty. I need to work with the 'copyProducts' array into the `forEach()` function.

```
app.controller("controllerApp", function($scope, serviceApp){

  var products = serviceApp.query(); 
  $scope.copyProducts = products;

  angular.forEach($scope.copyProducts, function(value, key){
    console.log("object: "+value);
  })

});
```

*Service*

```
app.factory("serviceApp", function($resource){
  return $resource("products.json", {}, {
        getAll: {
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code is wrong since `.query()` is asynchronous so it doesn't finish immediately and the result is not ready on the next line synchronously. So it needs a callback function to trigger once it's done with it's work.

```
serviceApp.query().$promise.then(function(res) {
  $scope.products = res;
  $scope.copyProducts = res;
  angular.forEach($scope.copyProducts, function(item) {
    console.log(item)
  })
});
```

Alternative:

```
serviceApp.query({}, function(res, headers){
  //etc
});
```

By the way, if you want to use the `getAll` method you have defined in your resource then you would **not** be using query()

```
  serviceApp.getAll().$promise.then(function(res){}).....etc
```

Comment: Yup just to point out why it's wrong, .query() is asynchronous so it doesn't finish immediately so it needs a callback function to trigger once it's done with it's work.  Also note its good to include error handling functions as well ($qProvider now complains by default if you don't have this)